# WPF Show wait cursor before application fully loads

Tags: wpf, cursor, prism, wait

I want to show the wait cursor before my WPF application, composed using CAL, fully loads.

In the constructor of the main window, I have the following code:

```
 public MainWindow([Dependency] IUnityContainer container)
        {                                                            

            InitializeComponent();

            Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
            ForceCursor = true;

            //this.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.AppStarting;

            // event subscriptions            

            PresenterBase.EventAggregate.GetEvent<ModulesLoadedEvent>().Subscribe(OnModulesLoaded);                                                               
        }
```

After all modules have been loaded, the following handler is invoked:

```
 private void OnModulesLoaded(EventArgs e)
        {
            allModulesLoaded = true;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;

        }
```

Problem is, I do not see this wait cursor.  What I am missing here?  FWIW, I got a hint from this post

[Showing the Wait Cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078766/showing-the-wait-cursor)

TIA.

Comment: Hi, Do you have the WaitCursorRequestEvent<bool> event defined anywhere?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for this question?  I am not using WaitCursorRequestEvent<bool>.  I have another type of event that fires when application is fully initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Prism bootstrapper in your app, and put the wait cursor code somewhere before you attempt to load the Prism modules.

Comment: This would also do it, thanks, but I have been able to get it working with the wait cursor code before in main window's constructor.